# SQL Server Configuration Manager startup parameter from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

We need to apply a change to about 100 computers, why I hope this is possible to do with an application.

All computers will need to:

1. Shutdown MSSQL service
2. Change startup parameter (add -m)
3. Start MSSQL services
4. Create database 'test'
5. Shutdown MSSQL service
6. Remove parameter -m
7. Start MSSQL service

All affected computers are running SQL Server 2012

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Comment: Googled a bit, but not sure what to Google after

Comment: Powershell should be your best bet! Try doing one thing at a time.

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell. See [Running Remote Commands](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819505.aspx).

Use the generic [`Get-Service`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347591.aspx) and [`Set-Service`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315324.aspx) to configure Windows Services, including the SQL Server service(s). See [Managing Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315239.aspx). Use the [SQL Server PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281947.aspx) provider for SQL Server specific stuff.

There are many tutorials online, eg. [Practical PowerShell for SQL Server Developers and DBAs](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/practical-powershell-for-sql-server-developers-and-dbas-%E2%80%93-part-1/).

Comment: Thanks, ServiceController is really helpful, but how do I start a service with parameters?